# SQL query to compare records having count greater than 1

Tags: sql, count

I have a table which contains id and answer columns which looks like:

```
| id | answer |
| 1  |  Yes   |
| 2  |   No   |
| 3  | Unsure |
| 1  |  No    |
| 1  | Unsure |
| 3  |  Yes   |
| 2  | Unsure |
| 4  | NULL   |
| 4  | Unsure |
| 4  | No     |
```

I want to the output in a way that if the userid has ever answered 'Yes' (like for example id 1) then the final output should have 1.
But if the userid has answered "No" and "NULL" then output should be "No"
Further if the userid has answered "Unsure" and "No" or "Unsure" and "Null" then output should be "Unsure"

Final Output:

```
| id | answer |
| 1  | Yes    |
| 2  | Unsure |
| 3  | Yes    |
| 4  | Unsure |
```

Comment: Given that you need to analyze the set of answers of the user, I think I would pivot the possible answers into a separate column, grouping by userid. Then you can easily analyze which answers the user has, and determine which is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use aggregation and `case` logic for this:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when Answer = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'yes'
             when sum(case when answer = 'unsure' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'unsure'
             else 'no'  -- or perhaps max(answer)
        end) as answer
from t
group by id;
```

If the only possibilities are "yes", "no", "unsure", and NULL, then you can take a short-cut:

```
select id,
       (case when max(Answer) = 'yes'
             then 'yes'
             when max(answer) = 'unsure'
             then 'unsure'
             else 'no'  -- or perhaps max(answer)
        end) as answer
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: really an interesting answer. Can you kindly tell me the use of max() function in your second option?

Comment: @sravee . . . `max()` is `max()` . . . I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to ask does max() count the answer field or the id field in this case?

Comment: @sravee . . . `max()` returns the maximum value of `Answer` in each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN (.Answer IS NULL OR .Answer = 'No') THEN 'NO' ELSE (.Answer) END AS 'FILTERED ANSWER'
```

Could This help you?